# How to add space between the words which is taken from the json in the frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

i'm trying to add spaces between the words which is coming from the json in the frontend ,but im unable to do that is there any way to do it
here is my code .

```
 const toSentenceCase = (str: string) => {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + '' + str.slice(1).toLowerCase()
  }
  return (
      <div className='fv-row mb-10'>
        <label className='form-label fs-6 fw-bolder text-dark d-flex'>Intent type</label>
        <Form.Select
          aria-label='Select htmlInputTypes'
          className='form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid'
          value={newIntentType}
          onChange={handleTypeChange}
        >
          {defaultJson.map((item, index) => (
            <>
              <option value='' disabled selected hidden>
                Select a Intent Type
              </option>
              <option key={index} value={item.type}>
                {toSentenceCase(item.type)}
              </option>
            </>
          ))}
        </Form.Select>
      </div>
```

and here is my json

```
  {
    "type": "textWithImage",
    "intent": {
      "id": null,
      "message": "Hi!",
      "trigger": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "payload": [
          {
            "url": "",
            "type": "null",
            "caption": "null"
          }
        ]
      },
      "userInput": false
    }
  },
```

The result which is coming:
Textwithimage

Expected result:
Text with image

i want this Text with image result but constantly im getting the wrong , i dont want the text to be camelCase but to be displayed in the sentance case is there any approch to handle it plese tell me.

Comment: Typo.  Your `toSentenceCase` is inserting an empty string `''` instead of a space `' '`.

Comment: @TimRoberts actually that empty string isn't doing anything about spacing, it's inserted after the first character only.

Comment: yaah that only im saying ,the strings were not doing anything

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it? Otherwise, please consider marking the answer that solved your problem accepted (the check mark under the up/down vote arrows next to the answer). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Find all uppercase characters following a lowercase character and replace them with a space inserted:

```
input.replaceAll(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

You can then use your function to capitalize the whole string.

You can also pass a replacer function to transform to lower case in one go:

```js
const input = 'TextWithImage';
const output = input.replaceAll(
  /([a-z])([A-Z])/g,
  (match, p1, p2) => `${p1} ${p2.toLowerCase()}`);
console.log(output);
```

Note that neither of the two methods will handle digits, umlauts or characters outside of the a-z ASCII range.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a space before every uppercase letter that is preceded by a lowercase letter in your string and then lowercase it. For example:

```js
const toSentenceCase = (str) => {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
         str.slice(1).replace(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g, ' ').toLowerCase()
}

console.log(toSentenceCase('textWithImage'))
```